# Wordpress' Contact Form 7 returns 404 but works on homepage

Tags: wordpress

I've installed Contact Form 7 (v 3.1.1) into Wordpress (v 3.3.1). It works fine on the homepage (which is a static Page called 'Home') but on any other page it does nothing and the console says:

`POST http://trademarkshop.ca/contact/ 404 (Not Found)`

I'm using `do_shortcode` to call it from both theme files:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="212" title="Contact form"]'); ?>`

I have `wp_footer()` in the footer and `wp_head()` in the header. I have no other plugins installed. I've even checked for `if(is_home())` restrictions. I also tried re-directing other pages to use the Home page template file, but still gives a 404 error.

I've never had this problem before. Any ideas would be very appreciated!

Comment: have you tried changing your permalinks to something else, then save, then change it back to /%postname%/ could be its not creating the htaccess file in the wp root, hence your permalinks arent working,

Comment: Hi Marty, thanks - that did the trick! If you want to submit it as answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried changing your permalinks to something else,

then save,

then change it back to /%postname%/

could be its not creating the htaccess file in the wp root, 
hence your permalinks arent working,

Marty

Answer (score 1):

use this  code

```
    <?php echo do_shortcode( '[contact-form-7 id="7" title="Contact"]' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

His problem is caused by a combination of two misconfigurations. First, AJAX JavaScript is not functioning on your contact form. Due to this problem, your contact form needlessly redirects after submission. Second, your contact form uses unavailable words in the names of input fields. This issue confuses WordPress, resulting in the 404 (“Not Found”) error.

https://contactform7.com/faq/my-contact-form-always-redirects-to-404-error-page-after-submission/

Answer (score 1):

Change your Contact form 7 field names. Because some names already using by wordpress may be is conflicting.

Example:

**name** to **username**

Answer (score 0):

Sometime that happen cause the code (id) in de form (When you try editing the error message on the left side there is a short html like code on witch there is an id) is not the same as the one when you go to dashboard>contact and the short code entry of the table. You need to change the first one to match the second one